# Robitium getCurrentActivity() returning previous activity

Tags: android, robotium

In my application there is a splash screen , which is taken care by "startupActivity.class" and after the splash , login screen comes which is "RootActivity.class". Here is my code

```
public class DNMBTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<StartupActivity> {
    Solo mSolo;
    public DNMBTest() {
        super("com.csg.cs.dnmb",StartupActivity.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mSolo=new Solo(getInstrumentation(),getActivity());
    }
public void testDNMBLaunch(){
mSolo.sleep(30000);
assertTrue("not the current activity", mSolo.waitForActivity("RootActivity"));

    }
    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mSolo.finishOpenedActivities();
        super.tearDown();
    }

}
```

I used sleep for a long duration so that startupactivity(the splash screen) gets finished and RootActivity gets launched.
But still after the sleep the assert fails also I tried getCurrentActitivity, which is returning startupactivity but not rootactivity

Answer (score 0):

use

> solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected RootActivity", "RootActivity");